# Postman not installed on ubuntu with snap

Tags: ubuntu, postman, google-chrome-os, snap

I'm trying to install postman on ubuntu 20.04 running on chromeos using snap

I first ran:

```
~$ sudo snap install postman
```

which appeared to work:

edit:

```
~/node/scrapedatatree$ glxinfo | grep -i vendor
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
Vendor: Mesa/X.org (0x1af4)
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa/X.org


username@penguin:~$ ls snap/
postman
```

But when I run postman:

```
username@penguin:~$ postman
The disableGPU setting is set to undefined
Not disabling GPU
No protocol specified
The futex facility returned an unexpected error code.Aborted (core dumped)
```

edit:

```
$ glxinfo | grep -i vendor
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
Vendor: Mesa/X.org (0x1af4)
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa/X.org
 
 $ lspci | grep VGA
(no output)

$ sudo find /dev -group video
find: ‘/dev/.lxd-mounts’: Permission denied
```

edit2:

```
:/etc/X11$ ls
Xreset  Xreset.d  Xresources  Xsession  Xsession.d  Xsession.options  app-defaults  fonts  rgb.txt  xkb
```

There is no xorg so the command doesn't work

edit3:

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE - no output

echo $DISPLAY - :0

echo $WAYLAND_DISPLAY - wayland-0
```

Answer (score 1):

Run with Wayland disabled by setting the variable to 1 before your snap run postman command:

`DISABLE_WAYLAND=1 snap run postman` or `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 snap run postman`

EDIT: To disable hardware acceleration in general, create a configuration file for Xorg:

If `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/disable-gpu.conf` does not exist:

```
echo -e 'Section "Extensions"\nOption "GLX" "Disable"\nEndSection' > /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/disable-gpu.conf
```

Applications installed with sudo that do not have full Wayland support - an ongoing issue with postman: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/9746 - may have trouble displaying their GUI. You can grant xhost access to your user and root with the following command run before you run your application:

```
xhost +SI:localuser:root
```

This is more secure than a generic `xhost +`. More information on this is available on AskUbuntu here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/614387/gksu-gtk-warning-cannot-open-display-0 and here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w

Comment: please see edit

Comment: Can you provide some details on your video drivers? You can check these following the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/28033/how-to-check-the-information-of-current-installed-video-drivers. There was a recent patch to postman to fix this, but your drivers might not be compatible

Comment: does that help?

Comment: Thank you for editing your question! I edited my answer to include another method that disables hardware acceleration either via a mesa environmental variable or a conf file

Comment: please see edit2

Comment: Please add the following commands and their outputs: `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` and `echo $DISPLAY` and `echo $WAYLAND_DISPLAY`

Comment: please see edit3

Comment: https://community.postman.com/t/installing-the-new-native-app-in-chromeos/5115/6